# Portfolio which replicates given payoff

Tags: finance, economics, applications

Consider the following payoff function:

$$p(S_T) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } S_{T} \leq 70 \\
S_{T}-70 & \text{if } S_{T} \in (70; 100] \\
-S_{T}+120 & \text{if } S_{T} \in (100; 120] \\
S_{T}-120 & \text{if } S_{T} \geq 120
\end{cases}
$$

Find portfolio of options which replicates this payoff.

Portfolio is combination of call and put options, which are functions:
call - $max\{S_{T}-K_{1},0\}$,
put - $max\{K_{2}-S_{T},0\}$, for some constants $K_{1},K_{2}$.

What is a general rule for exercises like this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is a portfolio of options? What is a payoff function? This is a math site, not an economics/finance one, so anything that's not a common mathematical term needs to be defined.

Comment: Also, your function is defined with two different values for $S_T \in (100;120]$. What is this supposed to say?

Comment: It is not considered good style to crosspost questions without informing people about that: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/option-strategy-portfolio-which-replicates-given-payoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it by trying to match the payoff, i.e. buying and selling certain quantities of calls and puts at the kinks or by a general algorithm, which is explained in this paper (together with some examples):

http://web.archive.org/web/20081203022044/http://longvega.com/Docs/project_paper.pdf

(unfortunately the tool that is being mentioned here is no longer available).

Comment: Thank you! Then $\frac{2}{3}(S_{T}-70)^{+}-\frac{5}{3}(S_{T}-100)^{+}+2(S_{T}-120)^{+}$ will be good for $S_{T} \geq 100$. For $S_{T} \leq 100$ we have $\frac{2}{3}(S_{T}-70)$... But maybe there is a mistake in this exercise...